# JS Q library - defer error catching

Tags: javascript, promise, deferred, q

I'm discovering Kris Koval Q library and I have a problem. Look at this simple code:

```
function getPromise1() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('Promise 1 OK');
        deferred.resolve();
    }, 1000);
    return deferred.promise;
}


function getPromise2() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('Promise 2 Failed');
        deferred.reject();
    }, 1000);
    return deferred.promise;
}

getPromise1()
    .then(getPromise2())
    .fail(function () {
        alert('Fail!');
    })
    .done();
```

I expect to see:

```
Promise 1 OK
Promise 2 Failed
```

and then show alert "Fail!", but the alert never shows. Instead of that I see warning in my console:

```
[Q] Unhandled rejection reasons (should be empty): ["(no stack) undefined"]
```

Why rejection is not handled and how can I handle it?

Comment: Try adding this. Q.stopUnhandledRejectionTracking(); to silence the logging

Comment: I think that Q.reject should have an Error instance as a reason. For example `deferred.reject(new Error('rejected'));` ?

Comment: warning is not a problem. Problem is that error is not handled - function .fail(...) is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `then` function, you should pass just the `getPromise2` function, not the result of `getPromise2()`

```
getPromise1()
    .then(getPromise2)            // NOTE: We are not calling it here
    .fail(function () {
        console.log('Fail!');
    })
    .done();
```